# How do Stripe Connect Payouts to Express Accounts work?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am building a platform where vendors list their products for buyers. I would like to know if I, as the platform own controls the amount of money sent to the vendors Express Stripe Connect account. For example, my website allows vendors to list their products for a $100 monthly fee. However, this fee can be charged only if the vendors makes at least 1 sale on my platform during the ongoing month. Vendors have Express Stripe connect accounts. If a buyer pays $500 to the vendor, can I deduct my $100 and send $400 to the vendors? Thank you.

Didn't find any info on this

Comment: You use Application Fees to take some of the amount from the payment for yourself and send the rest to the connected account.

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide?platform=web&payment-ui=checkout#accept-payment or https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges#application-fee describe it in detail